# Sieve of Eratosthenes in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, sieve-of-eratosthenes, x86

Hello I made a sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm on x86 assembly using NASM.

The highest number it can take is about 2 million and it takes like 2 seconds to complete.

Here's the code:

```
section .bss 
    buffer resb 100
    numbers resb 0

section .data
    arrayLength db 0

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        call getLength
        call initList
        call algorithm
        call printNumbers
        
        exit

        algorithm: 
            mov r10, 0     ;starting index
            mov r11, 2     ;every nth number to be crossed out
            loop3:
                mov rax, [numbers]
                mov rbp, [arrayLength]
                crossOut rax, r10, r11, rbp           ;if this returns 0 it means all non primes are already crossed out   
                jz return               
                call getIndex                           ; get next r10d and r11d
                jmp loop3
            return:
                ret

        getIndex:                 ;gets the next item that isnt already crossed out (0 means not crossed)
            mov rax, [numbers]
            loop2:
                inc r10
                inc r11

                mov r12b, byte [rax + r10]             
                cmp r12b, 0                     
                jnz loop2

                ret

        getLength:
            mov eax, SYSREAD
            mov edi, 1
            mov esi, buffer
            mov edx, 100
            syscall
            stringToNumber buffer         ; returns edi as number
        
            mov rbp, rdi                ; store in ebp
            sub rbp, 2                  ; if user enters 30 then array length should be 28
                                        ; since first array item is 2

            mov [arrayLength], rbp      ; save in pointer
            extern malloc
            call malloc
            mov [numbers], rax          
            ret

        initList:
            mov rbx, 0          ;index
            mov rbp, [arrayLength]
            mov rax, [numbers]
            
            initloop:
                mov byte [rax + rbx], 0

                inc rbx
                cmp rbx, rbp
                jl initloop
            ret

        printNumbers:
            mov rbp, [arrayLength]
            mov r8d, 2          ; value
            mov r9d, 0          ; index
            
            printLoop:
                mov rax, [numbers]
                mov r11b, byte [rax + r9]

                cmp r11b, 0
                je handlePrime
                
                loopend:
                    inc r9d
                    inc r8d
                    cmp r9, rbp        ;return at array length
                    jnge printLoop
                    ret
                    
            handlePrime:
                printNumber r8
                jmp loopend
  
    
    %macro crossOut 4
    xor rdi, rdi     ;edi keeps track of how many numbers were crossed out
                     ;if 0 end loop
    mov rbx, %1     ;array
    add rbx, %2     ;move position to starting index
    mov rax, %3     ;every nth number to be crossed out 

    mov rbp, %4     ; array length
    mov rcx, 0      ;counter
    
    %%loop:

        add rcx, rax
        cmp rcx, rbp
        jge %%exit

        add rbx, rax
        cmp byte [rbx], 0           
        je %%crossout

        jmp %%loop
    %%crossout:
        mov byte [rbx], 1
        inc rdi
        jmp %%loop

    %%exit:
        cmp rdi, 0
%endmacro


;example:
;"123"  -> starting from 1

;1 + 0 * 10  = 1
;2 + 1 * 10  = 12
;3 + 12 * 10 = 123

%macro stringToNumber 1
    mov rdi, 0                 ; number stored here
    mov ebx, %1  
    mov ecx, 0   

    %%loop:
    xor esi, esi
    mov sil, byte [ebx + ecx]
    sub sil, 48

    cmp esi, 9                  ;if this is greater than 9 the string has ended
    jg %%exit

    mov rax, 10
    mul rdi                     ; multiply by 10
    add rsi, rax
    mov rdi, rsi

    inc ecx
    jmp %%loop
    
    %%exit:
%endmacro
```

Comment: Your program suffers from buffer overrun. See my answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72502132/segfault-when-trying-to-get-a-byte-from-memory-address/72508116#72508116

Comment: Are you aiming for performance at all?  And/or for small/efficient code?  There's a lot of really inefficient stuff here, especially stuff like `je %%crossout` over a `jmp %%loop` instead of a `jne %%loop`.  And the fact that you're branching at all instead of unconditionally storing; is that an attempt to save cache bandwidth for larger problem sizes, by being read-only for cache lines you don't modify, instead of reading + dirtying it?  Or is that just a mistake?  If I was going to write an answer, not sure how much CPU performance detail would be relevant. (https://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: Have you tried writing this in C and looking at optimized compiler output?  Since you have silly inefficiencies like that `jcc` over a `jmp`, a compiler could show you better way for some things. It wouldn't do major changes, though, except maybe turning malloc + memset(0) into `calloc` for you.  (Also, why `malloc`?  That's the only libc function you use.  Unless you use any in `printNumber` or `exit` which you forgot to define)

Comment: Also, what CPU did you benchmark it on?  e.g. i7-6700k at 4.2 GHz (`echo 1000000 | perf stat ./sieve` can show you the average CPU frequency while it was running)

Comment: This doesn't assemble.  Besides a couple missing macros, you need to define macros *before* use.  You can call / jmp to a label you haven't defined yet, but NASM's preprocessor does care about source order.  It also reads from fd 1 (stdout) so you can't pipe a length into it, except via `echo 10000000 | perf stat --all-user ./sieve-buggy 1<&0`.  It takes 66 ms for a count of 10M, without the printing part.  (I just commented that out).  Perhaps your printing was taking the >99% of the 2 seconds, especially if you let it print to the terminal.

Comment: I was curious about performance of a bitmap implementation with `tzcnt` to search 64 bits at a time for the next prime to cross off.  So I wrote one.  https://godbolt.org/z/xaYKc4c4K.  Not really an answer to the code-review question, just a comment. Just to see how slow it would be, I used `bts [rbx], edx` to set bits in a bitmap, instead of doing faster manual indexing.  It's still fast enough that HW prefetch can't keep up well, and we get cache misses for sieve arrays that don't fit in L3 cache on my i7-6700k (with dual channel DDR4-2666).

Comment: Max n ~= 985771608 (~980 million) in 4.8 sec at ~2.5GHz (downclocked on memory bottleneck I guess).  Perf record says 95% of the time spent sieving, 5% spent iterating over primes.  (I don't actually print them, just materialize the value in a register where you can see them with GDB.  Seems to work, but I haven't test carefully, especially not near the max n.)  2 million finishes in 3.5 milliseconds.  (Again, *not* printing; if you let that go to the terminal, that would take most of your time.  And I'm not even formatting the numbers into strings, let alone making system calls for them)

Comment: Ah, the reason performance really drops with very large sizes is TLB misses, on my system.  Linux isn't using transparent hugepages for the mmap allocation, even with `enabled` = `always` and `echo defer+madvise >/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag`  (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html)

Comment: thanks, how can I see all the stats you listed like max value, length and what the time was used on?

Comment: @user259137:  Use `perf record --all-user ./a.out` / `perf report -Mintel` to profile clock cycles.  Or `perf stat --all-user -d`.  To find the max value that caused a problem for my version; I just ran it under GDB and looked at the value in R11 when it (intentionally) crashed.  Note the `jc abort` check after `tzcnt` in the sieve outer loop (to implement your getIndex search): if there's no prime in the next 63 to 56 bits of the bitmap, it just bails out because I didn't bother to write a loop.  But it bails out to a `ud2` instruction that will SIGILL, so I can see the current state in GDB.

Comment: I made benchmarkable versions, with a repeat loop around the sieve work, so they could be run for easily measureable and profileable times with small sizes (including small enough that bitmap vs. bool array doesn't make cache misses / memory bandwidth the only factor.) For n=40000, my version (https://godbolt.org/z/nh39TWxxb w. `perf stat` output) is ~3.1x faster than yours (https://godbolt.org/z/W69aoGGfY also w. perf out), both mostly L1d cache hits. Yours has 1% branch mispred. rate vs. 0.15% for mine (with less branching).  Skylake does surprisingly well with your data-dependent branching.

Comment: (I omitted printing from both versions, since that's not interesting, or at least something to benchmark separately.  And the i=2 case is done with `rep stosd` as a simple wmemset to reset for the next benchmark iteration.)

Answer (score 3):

- NASM supports [local labels](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-local-label.html). Using `.loop` instead of `loop2, loop3` etc improves readability.
- `getIndex` should be `getNextPrime`.
- `call malloc` does not belong to `getLength`. Do it in `initList`. BTW, you may as well `call calloc`, and don't bother to zero-fill the buffer manually.
- Instead of hand-rolled loops in `initList` and `getIndex` consider much more performant `rep stosb` and `rep scasb` respectively. Ditto for `printNumbers`.
- It seems that you try to avoid linking with `libc`. There is no reason to do it. `getLength` may benefit from calling `fgets` and `strtol`.
- What is `printNumber`? Yet again, I suspect that it does not `call printf`.

Comment: `rep stosb` is a fairly efficient `memset` ([Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231)), but conditional-rep operations like `repne scasb` don't have any fast-strings support in current CPUs, let alone ERMSB, so they go at 1 iteration per clock at best, unlike an SSE2 search that could easily go 16 bytes per clock.  (Or maybe 32 bytes per clock finding a non-zero, but with extra start/end overhead). Twice that with AVX2.  (There is no `rep scasb`, only `repe` or `repne`.  `f3 rep` is the same prefix byte as `f3 repe`, depending on which instruction it's applied to.)

Comment: Implementing your own int->string and string->int is an interesting exercise in seeing the algorithms for the really basic things that libc code does for you under the hood.  And it's not that much code ([How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)).  There's a `call malloc` so apparently they're not really trying to avoid libc, otherwise they'd want `mmap` or a big BSS buffer.  But yes `calloc` also gives you zeroed memory, usually taking advantage of mmap having zeroed it.

Answer (score 3):

[vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/277094/100620) has already covered some excellent naming and organizational points.  I won’t repeat them.

---

Your data structure is awkward.  You allocate `N - 2` bytes for the sieve, saving 2 bytes of memory, at the cost of needing to maintain both a `value` and `index` variables in registers, and needing to increment both.  If you just allocated the full `N` bytes, then `value` and `index` would be the same, only one variable would be needed.

---

Crossing out multiples of 2’s means when you cross out multiples of a larger prime, `p > 2`, you don’t need to cross out `2p` since it has already been done.  Similarly, crossing out multiples of 3 means when you cross out multiples of a prime `p > 3`, you don’t have to cross out `3p` since that has already been done.  In general, `crossOut` should begin crossing out at `p*p`.  For small prime numbers, this doesn’t save much, but as the primes get larger, the saved work becomes significant.

---

> keeps track of how many numbers were crossed out; if 0 end loop`.

It took me a while to convince myself that this loop termination condition wasn’t flawed.  It does work, but it is overly complex and slowing your code down.

First, why does it work?  If `p` is prime, then `p*p` will never be crossed out by any preceding step.  If `p*p` is less than your sieve limit, you will cross out that value at the very least, and the count will not be zero.  If `p*p` is greater than the sieve limit, then every smaller multiple of `p` will have been crossed out, and the count will be zero.

So, blindly executing `mov byte [rbx], 1` is all that is required.  No testing `cmp byte [rbx], 0` and no counting.  Less memory cycles, less testing and less jumping will significantly improve the speed of the loop.  Start the crossOut loop at `p*p` until that exceeds the sieve length.

Comment: ok thanks, but how will i stop the `algorithm` loop then? If i dont do counting

Comment: if I do p*p on every iteration isnt that gonna take a lot of perforamcne aswell?

Comment: You stop the `algorithm` loop when `p*p` exceeds the sieve length.  You run the inner `crossOut` loop starting from `p*p` and running up to the sieve length.  Computing `p*p` isn’t a performance penalty, especially if you reuse the value calculated in the outer loop for the inner loop’s start, instead of recalculating it.

Comment: This code didn't need separate registers for `value` and `index` in the first place in printNumbers.  If it wanted to save 2 bytes of dynamic allocation, it could have spent 1 byte of code-size on a displacement in the addressing-mode, like `movzx r11d, byte [rax + r8 - 2]`.  But yes, as it is now, that's a big over-complication, and multiple places need extra code-size (e.g. `sub rbp, 2`) to deal with the offset so it doesn't pay for itself.  Of course, code size can be shared between multiple running processes, but the size saving (or cost) is either 1 or 0 pages.  (Almost always 0 pages).